# namespace error : Namespace prefix oe for value on Property is not defined in c++

Tags: c++, libxml2

I am trying to create a xml content as follows,here I am using libxml2 and c++.I wrote wrapper over libxml2 library api's and trying to use that.But stuck with the following error when I am trying to add attribute to one of my element.I search in google to find out similar problems but not able to.
Please help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Environment>
 <PlatformSection>
  <Kind>NOVA</Kind>
  <Version>2013.1</Version>
  <Vendor>Openstack</Vendor>
  <Locale>en</Locale>
 </PlatformSection>
 <PropertySection>
  <Property oe:key="com.cisco.csr1000v.mgmt-interface" oe:value="GigabitEthernet1"/>
 </PropertySection></Environment>
```

my code looks like below, where I am using c++ libxml2 xmltextwriter.

```
    XmlWriter wtr;
      wtr.StartWriting("test.xml");
      wtr.StartDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
      wtr.StartElement("Environment");
      wtr.StartIndenting();
      wtr.StartElement("PlatformSection");
      wtr.WriteElement("Kind","NOVA");
      wtr.WriteElement("Version","2013.1");
      wtr.WriteElement("Vendor","Openstack");
      wtr.WriteElement("Locale","en");
      wtr.EndElement();
      wtr.StartElement("PropertySection");
      wtr.StartElement("Property");
      wtr.AddAttribute("oe:key","com.cisco.csr1000v.mgmt-interface");
      wtr.AddAttribute("oe:value","GigabitEthernet1");
      wtr.EndElement();
      wtr.EndElement();
      wtr.freeTextWriter();
```

where

```
     bool AddAttribute(const std::string& attribute_name,
                        const std::string& attribute_value) {
           return xmlTextWriterWriteAttribute(writer_,
                                           BAD_CAST attribute_name.c_str(),
                                           BAD_CAST attribute_value.c_str()) >= 0;
        }
```

My o/p giving the following error,

```
namespace error : Namespace prefix oe for key on Property is not defined
<Property oe:key="com.cisco.csr1000v.mgmt-interface" oe:value="GigabitEthernet1"
                                                                               ^
namespace error : Namespace prefix oe for value on Property is not defined
<Property oe:key="com.cisco.csr1000v.mgmt-interface" oe:value="GigabitEthernet1"
                                                                               ^
error : xmlTextWriterWriteDocCallback : XML error 201 !
I/O error : flush error
Entity: line 11: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
 </PropertySection>
                   ^
error : xmlTextWriterWriteDocCallback : XML error 5 !
xml is
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Environment>
 <PlatformSection>
  <Kind>NOVA</Kind>
  <Version>2013.1</Version>
  <Vendor>Openstack</Vendor>
  <Locale>en</Locale>
 </PlatformSection>
 <PropertySection>
  <Property key="com.cisco.csr1000v.mgmt-interface" value="GigabitEthernet1"/>
 </PropertySection></Environment>
```

Comment: And where is the namespace oe defined?

Comment: As I am new to this, I am able to understand how can I use nasmespace.

Comment: I tried to use as a string

Comment: You might want <xs:import> etc. in your xml.

Comment: could you please tell me, what might be the code changes I need to do in my above code?

Comment: Where is oe defined? If it's in a namespace, this may help: xmlTextWriterWriteAttributeNS http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlwriter.html#xmlTextWriterStartAttributeNS